# longest sub-array of different numbers maybe?

Tags: c++, c++14

this was a problem at a competition today, (which already ended, and my solution only got 25% of the examples correct)

the problem: A traveler traveled for N days, visiting a city on each day. Some cities have been visited multiple times. Write a program that tells us the length of the longest time period where the traveler went to a different city each day!

input : number of days (1 < N < 100,000) and in the next line, the "names" of the cities 1 < S[i] < N (which are just separate integers).

example input:

8

1 2 1 6 3 5 2 5

output : 5   ----- explanation: (1 6 3 5 2) (but I think by this logic 2 1 6 3 5 would also be correct?)

here is my solution, which gave a correct answer for 25% of the test cases, and wrong answer for the other 75%. We could only see two test cases, and the other one is with 10000 numbers, I would not copy that here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;



    int main()
    {
        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
        cin.tie(0);
        int n, input;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> cities;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> input;
            cities.push_back(input);
        }
        int maxlength = 0;
        set<int> myset;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(myset.find(cities[i]) != myset.end())
            {
                myset.clear();
            }
            myset.insert(cities[i]);
            if(myset.size() > maxlength)
                maxlength = myset.size();
        }
        cout << maxlength << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I believe this problem really just boils down to finding the longest set of different numbers in the given array (It's possible that I'm wrong). However, my solution was not completely correct, according to the site.

PS: I find it weird that it gives a correct answer sometimes, and an incorrect other times. It never runs out of the time barrier. I thought a program is either always correct or always incorrect, anyways, sorry if this question had already been asked here, I didn't find an exact same question like this. And obviously I'm open to all sorts of criticism, after all, we're here to learn.

Comment: It doesn't look like your second solution is correct. It looks like, although it's not clearly defined, that time travelling is |city_1 - city_2| with a traveler only visiting a destination city (so, for example, 1 3 doesn't visit 2). The correct answer had him traveling for 13 days. Your answer was 11. If a sequence is a valid path (no double visits), the distance traveled is sum(abs(firstDifference(city_subset))) where the first difference is size `n-1` with `f[n]:=city[n+1]-city[n]`. Look at `std::adjacent_difference`, `std::for_each(..., abs)` [pseudo code] and `std:accumulate`.

Comment: With `myset.clear()`, you're throwing out a sequence of uniquely visited cities that could be part of the longest sequence.

Comment: Example of the situation @1201ProgramAlarm describes: `1 2 3 1 4`. When you get to the  second `1`, you throw out _everything_ previous and miss the fact that `2 3 1 4` is a length-4 subsequence.

Comment: consider the case `1 2 3 4 5 2 6`, I don't think your code will give the correct answer of 5

Comment: Also not sure why you think a program must either be always correct or always incorrect. What if you'd written your program to just print `10` every single time? A stopped clock can be right twice a day, sort of thing.

Comment: @NathanPierson for 1 2 3 1 4 my code prints 3, which is wrong. But for 1 2 3 4 5 2 6 it prints 5, weird. But thank you for pointing this out, this flew over my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <complex>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> cities = {1, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 5};
        
    vector<int>::size_type startingCityIndex = 0;
    vector<int>::size_type maxStartCityIndex;
    vector<int>::size_type maxEndCityIndex;
    unsigned maxDistance = 0;
    unordered_set<int> visitedCities = {cities[0]};
    
    // Create distance vector F[n] := f[n+1] - f[n] (undefined for n = cities.size() - 1)
    vector<int> distances;
    for(vector<int>::size_type cityIndex = 0; cityIndex < cities.size() - 1; ++cityIndex)
        distances.push_back(abs(cities[cityIndex + 1] - cities[cityIndex]));
    
    // Suppose he travels to each city from startingCityIndex
    for(vector<int>::size_type traveledCityIndex = 1; traveledCityIndex < cities.size(); ++traveledCityIndex)
        // If he has not visisted the city
        if(visitedCities.find(cities[traveledCityIndex]) == visitedCities.end()) {
            // If the visisted city isn't the last one
            if(traveledCityIndex != cities.size() - 1)
                visitedCities.insert(cities[traveledCityIndex]);
            // Else it is the last one
            else {
                unsigned distance = accumulate(distances.cbegin() + startingCityIndex, distances.cend(), 0U);
                if(distance > maxDistance) {
                    maxEndCityIndex = traveledCityIndex;
                    maxStartCityIndex = startingCityIndex;
                }
            }
        // Else he has visited the city. Consider his path up to that point and start new path, clearing visitedCities and setting new startingCityIndex
        } else {
            unsigned distance = accumulate(distances.cbegin() + startingCityIndex, distances.cbegin() + traveledCityIndex - 2, 0U);
            if (distance > maxDistance) {
                maxDistance = distance;
                maxStartCityIndex = startingCityIndex;
                maxEndCityIndex = traveledCityIndex - 1;
            }
            while(cities[startingCityIndex] != cities[traveledCityIndex])
                visitedCities.erase(cities[startingCityIndex++]);
            visitedCities.erase(cities[startingCityIndex++]);
            --traveledCityIndex;
        }
    
    // Output answer
    for(vector<int>::size_type cityIndex = maxStartCityIndex; cityIndex < maxEndCityIndex; ++cityIndex)
        cout << cities[cityIndex] << " ";
    cout << cities[maxEndCityIndex] << endl;

    // Success!
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

O(n) memory due to the `unordered_set` potentially storing all cities (if the path is the entire input sequence).

`startingCityIndex` and `traveledCityIndex` march forward over the cities at most one time, never backtracking, so the loop, without `set::find` or `unordered_set::find`, would be O(n).

We have to account for the fact that up to n `find` methods might be called. `set::find` has worst case O(logn), making the overall algorithm O(nlogn). However, `unordered_set::find` has average case O(1) and worst case O(n), making average performance O(n) and worst case O(n^2). Hashing should be fairly uniform when applied to integers, so I'd go with the `unordered_set`, predicting it would have closer to O(1) than O(n) for `find`.

Answer (score -1):

Keep a deque of the current run, and a deque of the all time so far best run, and a set of elements in the current best run.

To advance, push the next city into the current run.  Determine if there is a duplicate by looking in the set.  If not, update best maybe, and continue.

If duplicate, walk current from front, removing from set and deque  until you see the "next city" you just added in the current deque.

This should be correct, but there is a simple optimization: replace deques with pairs of indexes (half open interval) into original list.  Avoids needless copies.  At 100,000 elements can keep them all in memory.

I think this in O(nlgn), as each element is added to the active deque once and removed once, plus set lookups.

Comment: I think you got the concepts correct, but I believe it's O(N) time, because `startingCityIndex` always marches forward to the first instance of the only duplicated city. `traveledToCityIndex` also marches steadily from `1` to `n-1`. Your and my answer seem to be the only ones that treat distance between two cities `i` and `k` as `abs(cities[i] - cities[k]|)`. I'm not sure why you got downvoted by people who didn't even provide an explanation. If anything, you at the least gave a decent starting point.

Comment: @uswr90 the set lookup is the lg n.  I guess unordered set removes thay factor.

Comment: Well, there is a cost and a benefit to `unordered_set`. Its average complexity is O(1), but it's worst case is O(n) if the hashing has collisions. `set`, on the other hand, has worst case performance O(logn). I'd predict that hashing integer, however, has few collisions, so I updated my solution to use `unordered_set`.